# Finding the longest common suffix recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm getting the correct results, but my method isn't the prettiest. Is there any way to do this with less code?

```
var longestSuffix = function(A, B) {
    return rec(A, B, 0);

    function rec(A, B, count) {
        if (!A.length || !B.length) return '';
        if (A[A.length - count - 1] === B[B.length - count - 1]) {
            console.log(A[A.length-count-1]);
            return rec(A, B, ++count) + A[A.length - count - 2];
        }
        return rec('','');
    }
};

console.log(longestSuffix('cababa', 'cabjklaba'));
```

Comment: Why not loop from the end until they do not match, and then return from there to to end of the string?

Comment: The problem asked for a recursive solution, but ya that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Recursive Solution Improvement

First, here's a rewrite of the answer you submitted yourself, which fixes a small bug and removes the inner function, which isn't needed.  Instead, we make the final two parameters optional:

```
function longestSuffix(X,Y,m,n) {
    var m = m === undefined ? X.length : m, 
        n = n === undefined ? Y.length : n, 
        keepGoing = X[m-1] && Y[n-1] && X[m-1] === Y[n-1];

    return keepGoing ? longestSuffix(X, Y, m-1, n-1) + X[m-1] : '';
};
```

Here's a different approach, slightly longer because I spelled everything out with variable names, but perhaps simpler in concept:

```
function longestSuffix (A, B, answer) {
    var answer = answer || '',
        aLast = A.slice(-1),
        bLast = B.slice(-1),
        A = A.slice(0,-1),
        B = B.slice(0,-1),
        done = !aLast || !bLast || aLast != bLast;

    return done ? answer : longestSuffix(A, B, aLast + answer);
};
```

You can make it shorter by, eg, removing `aMinusLast` and `bMinusLast` and replacing them inline with their definitions, but I like this expanded version because everything is clearly named, and the entire logic of the function can be seen at a glance in a single line.

### Loop solution

A loop may be more appropriate here.  Here's a very brief implementation which takes advantage of `slice`, which exists on strings as well as arrays.

The only ugly part of this is that we have to treat the case when both A fully matches B as a special case in the return statement.  Otherwise note that the final `slice(1)` just adjusts back for the final decrement.

```
function longestSuffix (A, B) {
    var i = -1;
    while (A.slice(i) == B.slice(i) && i >= -A.length) i--;
    return i < -A.length ? A : A.slice(i).slice(1)
};
```

This could be expanded for further clarity, but I figured I'd leave this one in compressed form, because it's so short.

Comment: I really like how you use the negative in your `slice`s ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a little cleaner in the sense that it is about 2 line less code and it doesn't do the `return rec('','')` to stop the recursion (which i thought was kind of ugly.

```
var LCSuffRec = function(X,Y) {
    return rec(X,Y, X.length, Y.length);
    function rec(X, Y, m, n) {
        if (X[m-1] === Y[n-1]) return rec(X, Y, m-1, n-1) + X[m-1];
        else return '';
    }
};
```

Comment: `LCSuffRec('hello', 'hello')` errors :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var longestCommonSuffix = function (left, right) {
    if (!left || !right) {
        return '';
    }
    var leftLength = left.length,
        rightLength = right.length;

    var longestCommonSuffixInternal = function(step) {
        if (step > leftLength  || step > rightLength  || left[leftLength  - step] !== right[rightLength  - step]) {
            return '';
        }
        return longestCommonSuffixInternal(step + 1) + left[leftLength  - step];
    }
    return longestCommonSuffixInternal(1); 
}
```

It passes these cases which yours doesn't:

```
longestCommonSuffix('hello', 'hello') // hello
longestCommonSuffix('', '') // ''
longestCommonSuffix('', null) // ''
```

I think it would be sufficient to only check that step has gone over the length of one of the two strings and not both but I left both checks in for completeness. It's not as elegant, but make something work first and then make it pretty :)